# why my postgres job stop running?

Tags: postgresql, job-scheduling, pgagent

I create a job to clean the database every day at 01:00.

According to statistic run OK from 3 months.
But today i realize the database size was very big so i check the jobs and hasn't run for one month.

Properties say last run was '10/27/2014' and statistics confirm run successful. 
Also say next run will be '10/28/2014' but looks like never run and stay frozen since then. 
(I'm using dd/mm/yyyy format)

So why stop running? 
There is a way to restart the job or should i go and delete and recreate the job? 
How can i know a job didn't run?  
I guess i can write a code if job isn't successful but what about if never execute?

[image]

> Windows Server 2008 
>   PostgreSQL 9.3.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit

Comment: It looks like the run is successful. It's just not doing what you want.

Comment: If you look at the picture and description last successfull run was octuber 27. Today is November 24. So almost 30 day without running.

Comment: Ah! I see - so this is what your screen looks like *today*. (1) Are there other jobs that have been running? and if not (2) Is the pgagent system service running on this Windows machine?

Comment: Ok, i think you got it. I just check the services. Even when pgagent say startup automatic. Didnt start it. I just start it now so I have to wait until 1:00 and see if run. Thanks.

Comment: Check the event logs and see if there's a reason it stopped. Then you can add your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the pgAgent service wasn't running.

When I Restart the Postgres service:

> Postgres service stop 
>   pgAgent stop because is a dependent service
>   Postgres service start
>   but pgAgent didn't

Here you can see pgAgent didn't start.
[image]